# In GCP bucket "NoSuchKey .... The specified key does not not exist." error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

`my GCP bucket load balancer static website when i call the url https://example.com, it works fine with rendering the default page https://example.com/index.htm

when i call the following url in browser  https://example.com/customers/index.htm, it throws the following error

`<error> <code>NoSuchKey</code> <message>The specified key does not exist.</message> </error>`

the resource index.htm is available under customers folder and can download from gcp bucket.

this url https://example.com/customers/index.htm need to be used in other applications for redirect.

the same above error for the following url too - https://example.com/custaccounts/index.htm

please advise what is wrong here and how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

calling this url in browser should work without any error - https://example.com/customers/index.htm
`

Comment: Does the path gs://<bucket>/customers/index.htm exist?

Comment: Use the CLI tool `gsutil` and verify that everything you expect is there, is really there.

Comment: yes, when i list that file using the following CLI command gsutil ls gs:<bucket>/customers/index.htm is available in that directory, the same i can see in gcp console view also, please help what i am missing here.

Comment: after analyzing further, i found index.htm is placed under Customers folder, not in customers(now realized. in GCP folders and files are case sensitive), so my url www.example.com/csutomers/index.htm throws error.

There huge number of places in different applications this url www.example.com/csutomers/index.htm call is happening, everywhere this error throws in browser, before www.example.com/csutomers/index.htm in hosted in windows server and there was no issue, recently moved to gcp and started this issue.

Comment: how to solve this issue, is there any advanced routing can be done  in load balancing when call happens  from clients to www.example.com/customers/index.htm to render www.example.com/Customers/index.htm, please help, my advance thanks to you.

Comment: This case sensitive issue is not only for this url, there are lot of other urls which have same issue as like i mentioned other issue in issue description - www.example.com/custaccounts/index.htm(CustAccounts), your help much appreciated on this.